# Why does the open source reload function not work?

Tags: angularjs, electron, reload

I developed a new `electron-angular` project.

When I execute it everything is working fine.

But when I change something in the code, the executing does not updating. like I wrote a function that set `x` value to `3`.
then I execute it and get the correct value. then I change the code to x=7 but still the executing shows x=3 until I close the electron window and execute again.
for this I find this command:

```
npm install electron-reload
```

and this code:

```
const electron = require('electron')

// Enable live reload for all the files inside your project directory
require('electron-reload')(__dirname);
```

then according to the website I found this stuff- it's supposed to be great. but it's not. can you help me with it?

Comment: What is the justification for the exe tag?

Comment: cause the problem is when i executing the project